# Is a MacBook 12" dual monitor setup possible?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I would like to use dual/two monitors with my macbook 12" (2016).

Is the device feasible of connecting, for example, to two **[LG UltraFine 4K Display](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HKMY2VC/A/lg-ultrafine-4k-display)** monitors? What kind of cables/connectors do I need?

Comment: For the 2015 model, there is a video on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GY2vZOJETl4

Comment: I am almost positive the MacBook is only capable of driving a single 4K monitor (and only at 30Hz - see here: http://9to5mac.com/2016/06/04/how-to-enable-4k-60hz-resolution-2016-macbook/). If you want two 4K monitors, your best bet is a 2015 MBPr or 2016 MBP

Comment: I do not restrict (as in *for example*) the monitors to be 4K, they can be of lower resolution, too. Although it would be great...

Answer (score 2):

As per https://support.apple.com/kb/SP712?viewlocale=en_US, I regret to inform you of this:

> ### **Graphics and Video Support**
>
> **Intel HD Graphics 5300**
>
> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on an external display, both at millions of colors
>
> ### **Display**
>
> **Retina display**
>
> 12-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit display with IPS technology
>   2304-by-1440 resolution at 226 pixels per inch with support for
>   millions of colors 16:10 aspect ratio Supported scaled resolutions:
>
> - 1440 by 900
> - 1280 by 800
> - 1024 by 640

Comment: According to Apple, the MB 12" 2016 has an Intel HD Graphics 515. In addition, as seen in the comments of my question, there is evidence for dual monitor setup of a 2015 model.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be evidence, using a dock, as presented by plugable (see [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11QnXXW39kE)), a [kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/plugable/plugable-ultimate-usb-c-universal-docking-station) project - 3 monitors @ 2K resolution.